# The parameterized query expects the parameter '@ProductImage', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Here, when I try to update image in a gridview, I can update everything pretty easily. When I do not select image and try to update other fields, I get above error.

Here is my Code.

```
 protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        int productId = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);

        TextBox productName = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ProductTextBox") as TextBox;
        TextBox description = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("DescriptionTextBox") as TextBox;
        TextBox itemsInSet = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ItemsTextBox") as TextBox;
        TextBox unitPriceOwner = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("PriceOwnerTextBox") as TextBox;
        TextBox unitPriceReseller = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("PriceResellerTextBox") as TextBox;
        TextBox shippingCost = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("CostTextBox") as TextBox;
        TextBox inOffer = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("InOfferTextBox") as TextBox;
        CheckBox visible = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("VisibleCheckBox") as CheckBox;

        FileUpload FileUpload1 = (FileUpload)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("FileUpload1");

        Product product = new Product();
        product.ProductID = productId;
        product.ProductName = productName.Text;
        product.Description = description.Text;
        product.ItemsInSet = Convert.ToInt32(itemsInSet.Text);
        product.UnitPriceOwner = Convert.ToInt32(unitPriceOwner.Text);
        product.UnitPriceReseller = Convert.ToInt32(unitPriceReseller.Text);
        product.ShippingCost = Convert.ToInt32(shippingCost.Text);
        product.InOffer = Convert.ToBoolean(inOffer.Text);
        product.Visible = visible.Checked;

        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            int length = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
            product.ProductImage = new byte[length];
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(product.ProductImage, 0, length);
        }
        else
        {
            ProductBL.GetImage(productId);
        }

        ProductBL.UpdateProduct(product);

        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        GridView1.DataSource = ProductBL.GetProducts();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

This is my Business Logic Layer code for Product.

```
public static void UpdateProduct(Product product)
    {
        string query = "UPDATE [Products] SET [ProductName] = @ProductName, [Description] = @Description, [ItemsInSet] = @ItemsInSet, " +
                        "[UnitPriceOwner] = @UnitPriceOwner, [UnitPriceReseller] = @UnitPriceReseller, [CategoryID] = @CategoryID, " + 
                        "[ShippingCost] = @ShippingCost, [InOffer] = @InOffer, [ProductImage] =@ProductImage, [Visible] = @Visible WHERE [ProductID] = @ProductID";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", SqlDbType.Text).Value = product.ProductName;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", SqlDbType.Text).Value = product.Description;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemsInSet", SqlDbType.Int).Value = product.ItemsInSet;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitPriceOwner", SqlDbType.Int).Value = product.UnitPriceOwner;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitPriceReseller", SqlDbType.Int).Value = product.UnitPriceReseller;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CategoryID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = product.CategoryID;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShippingCost", SqlDbType.Int).Value = product.ShippingCost;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InOffer", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = product.InOffer;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Visible", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = product.Visible;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", SqlDbType.Text).Value = product.ProductID;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductImage", SqlDbType.Image).Value = product.ProductImage;

        DbUtility.UpdateDb(cmd);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check like this before update:

```
SqlParameter unitsParam = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductImage", SqlDbType.Image);
if (product.ProductImage == null)
{
    unitsParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
}
else
{
    unitsParam.Value = product.ProductImage
}
```

Comment: Probably you mean _product.ProductImage == null_ and for completeness add also the else part

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Updated

Comment: Now, I am getting this error. Additional information: Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with image.

Comment: @Orion,  Try this `cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductImage", SqlDbType.Image).Value = product.ProductImage == null ? DBNull.Value : product.ProductImage;`

Comment: @Div, i tried that too. When I use above code, i get this error. Error 1 Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DBNull' and 'byte[]' .. Using byte[] as datatype for Image.

Comment: @Orion Let update that like here and let me know `cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductImage", SqlDbType.Image).Value = product.ProductImage == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : product.ProductImage;`

Comment: @div. Tried that too. Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ProductImage', column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated. What does this mean?

Comment: @Orion, I think it does mean that your filed `ProductImage` is not `nullable` Isn't it?

Comment: @Div. Not nullable. When I update image field in gridview, it is saving new image. When I dont select image field, I want old stored image to be showed up. What Can i do for this? Kindly, have a look at above code. Thanks in Advance

Comment: @Orion, You should allow that filed to add null value into it, so alter your table schema and check.

Comment: @Orion, Does it make sense?

Comment: @Orion, I think you should do some changes in stored procedure

Comment: Like this `productImage   = COALESCE(@productimahe,  productImage)`

Comment: @Div . Thanks for your Input my friend. cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductImage", SqlDbType.Image).Value = product.ProductImage == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : product.ProductImage; This worked for me and I added few lines of code ... Byte[] image;

                image = ProductBL.GetImage(productId);
                product.ProductImage = image;